# How did 'et' and 'iam' compound to signify "even" in 'etiam'?

Tags: etymology

How does "and, also" + "now, already" compound to signify "even"? I don't understand how combining the notions of "and, also" + "now, already" can yield "even". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etiam):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

*Etiam* gets much of its meaning from *et* (i.e, as a conjunction and in other respects), but it also gets its emphatic (as well as temporal) meaning from *iam*. This is consistent with the *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/even)* definition of *even* which asserts that it is "used to emphasize a comparison".

**Long answer:**

*Etiam* is similar to *et* in its use as a conjunction as well as in having a somewhat overlapping meaning. Note that Lewis' *[An Elementary Latin Dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=et&la=la#lexicon)* includes the meaning *even* in its definition for *et*:

> ***et*** — I. adv., adding to a fact or thought, *also, too, besides, moreover, likewise, as well, even*...

In some cases, *et* has even been used by some authors in ways that could be interchangeable with *etiam*, as [Gildersleeve](https://archive.org/details/gildersleeveslat00gilduoft/page/302) notes:

> Instead of **etiam**, **et** is occasional in PLAUTUS, in a change of
>   person. CICERO uses it also after an adversative conjunction, as
>   **vērum et**; also after **nam** and **simul**; more often when a pronoun follows, as **et ille**, **et ipse**. CAESAR never uses it so,
>   SALLUST rarely, but it becomes common from Livy on. (*Gildersleeve's
>   Latin grammar*, p. 302)

Although *etiam* is sometimes used in a temporal sense (when it means *still*, *even now*, etc.), its significance seems to also take on new meaning in its composition as ***et + iam*** more as a matter of emphasis rather than one of time. That is, it adds something new and at the same time emphasizes it, as if to say, "*Now* take note of this," or schematically, "**A**, **B** *and now even* **C**..."

The emphatic force of *etiam* has been noted by a number of grammarians. For example, [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=etiam&la=la#lexicon):

> To annex a more important idea, *and even*, *nay*, *even*...

*[Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/adverbs)*:

> ***Etiam*** (***et iam***; also, even) is stronger than ***quoque*** (also) and usually precedes the emphatic word, while ***quoque***
>   follows it.

[Gildersleeve](https://archive.org/details/gildersleeveslat00gilduoft/page/300):

> **Etiam**, *even* (*now*), *yet*, *still*, exaggerates (heightens), and generally precedes the word to which it belongs. (*Gildersleeve's
>   Latin grammar*, p. 301)

*[A Grammar of the Latin Language](https://archive.org/details/grammaroflatinla00zumprich/page/252)* (where, besides speaking of the emphatic role of *etiam*, it is also compared to *et*):

> *Etiam* and *quoque* are in so far different in their meaning, that *etiam*, in the first place, has a wider extent than *quoque*, for it contains also the idea of our "even;" and, secondly, *etiam* adds a
>   new circumstance, whereas *quoque* denotes the addition of a thing of
>   a similar kind. Hence *etiam* is properly used to connect
>   propositions. This difference seems to be correctly expressed in
>   stating that *etiam* is "and farther," and *quoque* "and so, also." As
>   in this manner *quoque* refers to a single word, It always follows
>   that word; *etiam*, in similar cases, is usually placed before it, but
>   when it connects propositions its place is arbitrary. *Et*, too, is
>   sometimes used in the sense of "also," in classical prose; e.g.,
>   Curt., iii., 31, *non errasti, mater, nam et hic Alexander est*; Cic.,
>   *de Legg.*, ii., 16, *quod et nunc multis in fanis fit*, for *nunc quoque*; in *Verr*., iv., 61, *simul et verebar*; and v., l, *simul et
>   de illo vulnere — multa dixit*; and often *non modo — sed et*; e.g.,
>   Cic., in Verr., i., 1, *non modo Romae, sed et apud exteras nationes*;
>   Nepos, *Thrasyb*., 1, *non solum princeps, sed et solus bellum
>   indixit*. (See Bremi's remark on this passage, who states that sed et
>   is not merely "but also," but always "but even." ) But passages of
>   this kind are not very numerous, and not always certain, for the MSS.
>   usually have *etiam*, so that this use of *et* in prose (for poets
>   cannot be taken into account) must at least be very much limited, and
>   it should not be used to that extent in which modern Latinists apply
>   it. (Zumpt, et al, *A Grammar of the Latin Language*, pg. 253)

The foregoing is also interesting in that, when the author speaks of the meaning of *etiam* as "and farther", he seems to be trying to associate the idea of *still* with that of *even*. It's as if to say that the conjunction *etiam* takes us *still farther* to the point of emphasis.